# Why is the local timestamp equal to the UTC timestamp?

Tags: php, timezone, utc

If `date()` formats a local time/date, and `gmdate()` formats a GMT/UTC date/time, why is this true?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
var_dump(date('U') === gmdate('U')); // true
```

On the command line:

```
$ php -r "date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); var_dump(date('U') === gmdate('U'));"
bool(true)
```

Why is the local timestamp equal to the UTC timestamp for different time zones?

Comment: Timestamps are always in UTC. Formatted dates are localized according to the timezone setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because timestamps are seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). Notice the GMT? No matter what time zone you're in, the timestamp is relative to that time and timezone.

What you really want to do is:

```
$local = new DateTime();
$local->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$gmt   = new DateTime();
$gmt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($local === $gmt);
```

Comment: Did you mean $gmt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Makes sense why there's no `gmtime()`